# Add bullets in magnific popup gallery

Tags: magnific-popup

I have added magnific popup gallery in my web page, everything works great. Just I want to know, is there any possibility add bullets in popup gallery below image in `.mfp-bottom-bar`.

Answer (score 0):

The gallery example on [Magnific's demo/homepage](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) shows at least one way to achieve this, by feeding some markup into the return value of a function in the `titleSrc` option in the `image` option of the popup.  In that example (from the page's source):

```
 $('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
   ...
   image: {
     ...
     titleSrc: function(item) {
       return item.el.attr('title') + '<small>by Marsel Van Oosten</small>';
     }
   }
 });
```

The above case appends a `<small>` element to the current link's title attribute value/text, but you could presumably return some other `<ul><li>...</li></ul>` markup, or use jQuery to grab some existing `<ul>` in the markup (if relative to the current item, then presumably using `item.el` to help locate it).

Comment: It will add the elements for each image (if it is given in `titleSrc`). Another way could be to add through jQuery, but I think magnific is not giving total counting of images in gallery.
Changing will be possible by 
`callbacks: {
 ...
  change: function() {
    console.log('Content changed');
    console.log(this.content); // Direct reference to your popup element
  },`